# Is there any way to get the sale status of an NFT (listed on marketplaces like OpenSea) using their contract address?

Tags: python, solidity, nft, web3py

I am trying to create a minting function in python (using web3.py) that takes the contract address, minting function, and arguments from the Solidity Contact (along with other necessary inputs).
I am able to achieve the minting functionality but now I am thinking how to determine if the sale of that particular NFT is live or not. Is there any way to get this information using the contact address?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try with https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-orders